# How can I join tables with where condition in spring-data-jpa using specification?

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa

As the question's title, how I can join tables with where condition in spring-data-jpa using specification. May you help me?

**People.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "people")
public class People {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
    private Integer people_id;
    @Column
    private Integer peopleAge;    
    with getters and setters...
}
```

**Home.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "home")
public class Home{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
private Integer homeId;
@Column
private String homeName;
@Column
private String peopleId;
 with the getter and setter ..}
```

**PeopleRepository.java**

```
public interface PeopleRepository extends JpaRepository<People, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<People> {
}
```

**PeopleSpecification.java**

```
public class PeopleSpecification implements Specification<People> {
    private SearchCriteria criteria;

    public PeopleSpecification(SearchCriteria criteria) {
        this.criteria = criteria;
    }

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<People> root, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder builder) {
        if (criteria.getOperation().equalsIgnoreCase("==")) {
            return builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(
                    root.<String> get(criteria.getKey()), criteria.getValue().toString());
        }else if (criteria.getOperation().equalsIgnoreCase("%")) {
return builder.like(
                        root.<String>get(criteria.getKey()), "%" + criteria.getValue() + "%");        }
}
```

**SearchCriteria.java**

```
private String key;
    private String operation;
    private Object value;
getter, setter, constructor
```

**PeopleService.java**

```
public interface PeopleService{


    public List<People> searchPeople(Integer peopleAge, StringhomeName);
```

**PeopleServiceImpl.java**

```
    public class PeopleServiceImpl implements PeopleService {

        @Autowired
        PeopleRepository peopleRepository;

        @Override
        public List<People> searchPeople(Integer peopleAge, String homeName) {
            peopleAge = 20;
            homeName = "example";
            PeopleSpecification condition1 = null;
            if (peopleAge!= null) {
                nameCond = new PostSpecification(new SearchCriteria("peopleAge", "==", peopleAge));            
            }

            PeopleSpecification condition2 = null;
            if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(homeName)) {
                nameCond = new PostSpecification(new SearchCriteria("homeName", "%", homeName));            
            }

    return postRepository.findAll(Specifications.where(condition1).and(condition2);
}}
```

I want to join people and home like sql as below:

> SELECT * FROM people p INNER JOIN home h ON p.peopleId ==h.peopleId
>   WHERE p.age = 20 AND h.homeName like "%example%"

How can I implement with complex conditions?

Comment: Can you edit your code? It seems unclear, PeopleServiceImpl

Comment: @ByeBye i edited

Comment: Still, `PeopleServiceImpl` has `PeopleSpecification condition1 = null;` but it always null.

Comment: @ByeBye: I updated. It's minor :|.

Comment: Please take you time on that and provide code which is valid.